# Why doesn't Marklogic data hub restart after reboot

Tags: linux, marklogic

I have installed ML Data Hub 4.3.2 ( I already have ML 9 server running on the same box  ) on Red Hat Enterprise linux 7.6 using the quick-start-4.3.2.war file.
This is done as root user ( its a Dev box ).

It installs and starts OK on port 9000, and I can go through and configure a project.

But, when I reboot the server, it wont restart and I am unsure on how to manually restart the services.

I tried to restart apache but it seems apache is not installed on the linux box.

How do I get the MarkLogic Data Hub to restart after a reboot, or is it designed not to do that?

Any help appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you are talking about getting the Data Hub Quick Start to start automatically after a reboot.  Quick Start is just a development tool, so is not actually 'installed' on the host server, it is just launched on the host server.

There are a number of different approaches to doing this, here are a couple of options:

The answers on this question detail many of them:

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/56957/how-to-start-an-application-automatically-on-boot

The easiest of the options mentioned in those answers is using the crontab.

Comment: OK, thank you. Can I please confirm - is the data hub download URL https://developer.marklogic.com/products/data-hub  , or is this URL just for the quick start version of it?  The web link says "quickstart" in its name but the downloaded  .war file doesnt have that in its name. It is a little confusing. If this is the real data hub, then great I can keep pushing on with installing the proper data hub that will restart on reboot.

Comment: @steve Yes, that is the Quckstart.  To install DHF without the quickstart, you can follow the guide here:  https://docs.marklogic.com/datahub/5.2/projects/create-project-using-gradle.html

Comment: Hi Michael, thank for your help, I will try an install using gradle. Maybe I could suggest ML could alter thier doco to have a "Quickstart DH Install" section and a "Permenant DH Install" section, because its not 100% obvious what to do, unless you live in the ML world? Cheers.